# CRLS merge sort boundary code understanding in C code

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

```c
void merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r) {
    int *tmpL, *tmpR;
    int boundary;
    int n1, n2;
    int i, j, k;

    n1 = q - p + 1;
    n2 = r - q;

    tmpL = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n1 + 1));
    tmpR = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n2 + 1));

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        tmpL[i] = A[p + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        tmpR[j] = A[q + j + 1];

    boundary = tmpL[n1 - 1] > tmpR[n2 - 1] ? tmpL[n1 - 1] + 1 : tmpR[n2 - 1] + 1;
    tmpL[n1] = boundary;
    tmpR[n2] = boundary;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    for (k = p; k <= r; k++) {
        if (tmpL[i] <= tmpR[j]) {
            A[k] = tmpL[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            A[k] = tmpR[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

    free(tmpL);
    free(tmpR);
}
void merge_sort(int A[], int p, int r) {
    int q;

    if (p < r) {
        q = (p + r) / 2;
        merge_sort(A, p, q);
        merge_sort(A, q + 1, r);
        merge(A, p, q, r);
    }
}
```

I could not understand this infinite boundary code exactly `boundary = tmpL[n1 - 1] > tmpR[n2 - 1] ? tmpL[n1 - 1] + 1 : tmpR[n2 - 1] + 1;`

Thanks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmyUg.png     (circled in blue)

This is a conditional statement, `A> B? C:D`. 
If `A> B` is true then evaluate C, else evaluate D.
But I still do not understand the boundary part. 
Is this the same as adding two while loops to deal with when one half of them have remaining elements and append them to the end of new arrays?

If I don't initialize them as infinite boundary they may give me a segmentation fault.

Comment: fix your image view by using !, brackets [image name] and quotation (url\image.png) marks.

Comment: Please include all of the code from the image in your question. Without the context of the rest of the code, the question may not be clear to others reading this. Also at the end of the code, add a line showing how mergesort is called, such as mergesort(A, 0, size-1).

Comment: I edited the tags to include sorting and to remove "boundary" which is normally used with a different meaning here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: okay okay thanks, I will once I have 15 reputations^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code uses a common approach for `mergesort` where copies are made of both subarrays with an extra element at the end, set to a value greater than the maximum value of both arrays.

The statement `boundary = tmpL[n1 - 1] > tmpR[n2 - 1] ? tmpL[n1 - 1] + 1 : tmpR[n2 - 1] + 1;` attempts to compute the value `boundary` as 1 plus the maximum value of `tmpL` or `tmpR` depending on which is greater. It uses a ternary expression which is roughly equivalent to writing:

```
    if (tmpL[n1 - 1] > tmpR[n2 - 1])
        boundary = tmpL[n1 - 1] + 1;
    else
        boundary = tmpR[n2 - 1] + 1;
```

The merging loop can then use a single test `k <= r` to stop the loop and `i` will equal `n1` and `j` will equal `n2` when `k` reaches `r + 1`.

This approach is broken in many respects:

- if either subarray contains the maximum value `INT_MAX`, the computation of `boundary` will overflow and cause undefined behavior. Even if the overflow does not cause a fatal side-effect, the value of `boundary` will be meaningless, causing incorrect results or other undefined behavior.
- testing for array boundaries is simple, much simpler than this incomplete work-around.
- this method requires both arrays to be allocated and copied, whereas the right half would not require saving because `merge` would not overwrite values that have not already been copied.

In my opinion, this method should not be taught at all.

Here is an alternative implementation without these shortcomings:

```c
void merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r) {
    int *tmpL;
    int n1, n2;
    int i, j, k;

    // It is much simpler to consider q to point to the first element of
    // the second subarray and r to point after the last element of that array.
    q++;
    r++;

    n1 = q - p;  // number of elements in the left sorted subarray
    n2 = r - q;  // number of elements in the right sorted subarray

    tmpL = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n1);
    if (tmpL == NULL) {
        // Report this fatal error or fall back to a different 
        // algorithm that does not require allocation, such as
        // heapsort or insertion sort.
        return;
    }
    // Make a copy of the left subarray as elements may be overwritten in the loop.
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        tmpL[i] = A[p + i];
    }

    // Merge the elements of the subarrays:
    // - if all elements of the left array have been merged, 
    //   the remaining elements of the right subarray are already in place
    // - if k has reached r, all elements have been sorted
    for (i = j = 0, k = p; i < n1 && k < r; k++) {
        if (j >= n2 || tmpL[i] <= A[q + j]) {
            // Take the element from tmpL if the right subarray is empty
            //    or if it is no greater than the next one from the right subarray.
            A[k] = tmpL[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            // Otherwise take the element from the right subarray.
            A[k] = a[q + j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    free(tmpL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

merge() is supposed to merge two already sorted runs in A, from A[p] to A[q], and from A[q+1] to A[r] (inclusive). TmpL and TmpR are created, each with space for 1 extra element at the end to be used as a sentinel value that is greater than any value in either TmpL or TmpR. The ternary statement sets boundary to the greater of the last values in TmpL and TmpR, then adds 1 to this value to create a sentinel value that is stored at the end of TmpL and TmpR. This eliminates the need to check the indexes "i" or "j" to see if the end of TmpL or TmpR has been reached, in which case the rest of TmpR or TmpL would be copied back to A[].

For most programming languages, instead of using the ternary statement, the code could have just set boundary to INT_MAX or one of the other max values from the include file limits.h (or for C++, climits):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits

If sorting floats or doubles, boundary can be set to infinity.

The reason for the segmentation fault is that without the sentinel value, the code may run beyond the end of either TmpL or TmpR causing the fault.

A problem with this method for sorting is that A[] may already contain the maximum possible value, in which case this approach will fail. In the case of integers, adding 1 to the maximum value will wrap around to the smallest value.

Comment: Thank you^^'adding 1 to the maximum value will wrap around to the smallest value.' you mean this line right? tmpL = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n1+1));

Comment: can I just use two while loops like if left array (sorted) elements all bigger than my right array(sorted) so I 'append ' all of them in the end of  newly merged array ? like python code? I learned datastructure in python, switched to C code I feel very confusing and hard to adapt..

Comment: @meow - "append at end of newly merged array?" - yes, this is how merge is normally implemented. When the end of either left or right is reached, then the remainder of right or left is appended to the already merged data. Although in java, this [optimized top down merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822461/why-is-recursive-merge-sort-function-displaying-on2-time-complexity/48841850#48841850) has a typical merge function. The alternating top down ...atob and btoa functions are used to avoid having to copy data by changing the direction merge for each level of recursion.

Comment: @meow - in my last comment, I included a link to a typical merge function that works as you asked. However, the question you posted is about a different implementation that relies on using a value greater than any value in A[] as a "sentinel" to avoid having to check to see if the end of left or right was reached, which won't work if one or more values in A[] are the maximum possible value. It's not a method that is normally used.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I  read all of them, very helpful, thank you!

Comment: I read other implementations online, it is fine just not to use a pointer like a python code.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/.  much better than the text code

Comment: @meow -  I found an example of [optimized top down merge sort in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665863/mergesort-implementation-is-slow/41668335#41668335) . After the quicksort in this old answer, here is [optimized bottom up merge sort and 4 way merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844613/optimized-merge-sort-faster-than-quicksort/34845789#34845789) . In these examples, b[] is a temp working array passed by the caller. The data to be sorted is in a[].